# My flash gallery is not coming up

Tags: flash

I'm working with a flash image slideshow and I'm having trouble getting it to read from my xml file for the captions, the same thing with the images. I've changed the paths on the  as well as  is there anything I'm missing, any other path im supposed to change to read off of the correct XML file and image directory? Here's the link - http://innspireconference.com/archive_2011.php

Comment: The link seems to work fine for me.  Do you have any more info? Which browser are you using? Could it simply be a slow connection? Is there any debugging output (flashlog.txt)?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with comment, it works fine for me.

Problems I've had with similar stuff, was depending on how you're referencing your external files, flash will treat innspireconference.com and www.innspireconference.com as two different domains and won't read from one if the swf is on the other.

Get the debug player from adobe and it will show you any errors.